# how to display specific account records in popup in suitecrm

Tags: php, crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I've created one `'account_category'` field in `account module`. It is dropdown and have following options:

1. principle
2. customer
3. supplier
4. manufacturer

I created Account relationship with Opportunity module.

In the Account popup i want to display only those records which have account_category as principle.

My file path : custom/modules/opportunity/metadata/editviewdef.php

```
1 => 
          array (
            'name' => 'opportunities_accounts_1_name',
           'displayParams' => 
            array (
              'initial_filter' => '&account_category_c="Principle"',
            ),
          ),
```

But it is not working..

Please help to filter accounts on the basis of account_category_c as principle

Comment: someone please send solution for this...please

Comment: still awaiting for your response...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the word _advanced like this:

```
'initial_filter' => '&account_category_c_advanced="Principle"',
```

see:

http://academe.co.uk/2013/03/sugarcrm-relate-field-passing-default-values-to-pop-up-select-form/

http://developer.sugarcrm.com/2011/08/31/howto-using-a-relate-field-to-populate-a-custom-field/

Comment: _advanced is not working for this..1 => 'account_name',
            'displayParams' => 
            array (
              'initial_filter' => '&account_category_c_advanced="Principle"',
            ),

Comment: Take a look at http://academe.co.uk/2013/03/sugarcrm-relate-field-passing-default-values-to-pop-up-select-form/ this explains how the initial filter works.